# FFT in Octave is hanging

Tags: fft, octave

I am using Octave in Ubuntu ubuntu 11.10.

I am trying to find FFT of large datapoints in Octave

When i enter a vector with large number(around 1000 to 1500),Octave is hanging.

```
    x=[1 2 3 4.....1500]
```

Did anyone face the same problem or is it generally slow.

Comment: It works fine for me with Octave 3.2 in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It tried with 1000 smaples..its hanged :(

Comment: also works just fine on 3.6.2. `x = 1:5000; y = fft(x)` takes 0.00024319 seconds on a 7 year old home desktop

Comment: I kept values here,Can your try on test values at    [Test Values](http://textsave.de/?p=145805)

Comment: I was wondering why Ubuntu 11, then I noticed this is a really old question. Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I just changed some typo today. Never mind. I am not facing this issue.